# sheet Getting an error "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'valid'" while executing Python Google Sheet API?

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

I'm running Python Google Sheet API, and getting this error AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'valid'?

I'm new to Python Google Sheet API; Didn't get enough to try different things to resolve it.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly']

# The ID and range of a sample spreadsheet.
SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID = '1dQ_WGhmQHClQ8tY-0djLhOltF9aRhtU7p2WmDEdRFYg'
SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME = 'Sheet1!A2:E2'

def main():
"""Shows basic usage of the Sheets API.
Prints values from a sample spreadsheet.
"""
creds = 'C:\\Users\\Nimit\\Desktop\\Google\credentials.json'
# The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
# created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
# time.
if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
    with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
        creds = pickle.load(token)
# If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            'credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    # Save the credentials for the next run
    with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
        pickle.dump(creds, token)

service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials = creds)

# Call the Sheets API
sheet = service.spreadsheets()
result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,
                            range=SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME).execute()
values = result.get('values', [])

if not values:
    print('No data found.')
else:
    print('Name, Major:')
    for row in values:
        # Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
        print('%s, %s' % (row[0], row[4]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'valid'

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to assign creds to json file location. The credentials will be automatically written to filesystem when you run it for the first time and log in.

```
creds = None
```